# Pictures on website don't show for other viewers

Tags: html, css, image, web

I made a website.

When I open it from Sublime Text 3, everything works, but when I tried to open the file that I had sent (the correct one), the pictures did not show.

Why? Is something wrong with the code?

Comment: What is the path of the image you are referencing? Is it an external URL or a local path?

Comment: It is a local path. Maybe thats the problem! How can I link to a external URL?

Comment: Yeah that is the problem. I would recommend just using something like https://imgur.com/upload to upload an image on the web. Once uploaded you can typically right click on the image and just press copy image address and paste that address into a src attribute. This will let anyone who has an internet connection view the image.

Comment: Are you just send the HTML file to your teacher? If so, you might want to think about compressing all the files in a folder, so the links to images work.

Comment: Yes now it worked! Thank you!!

Comment: How do i do that DollarChills?